# What cool frameworks are there on Java/Ruby etc. that don't exist on .NET?

Tags: java, .net, ruby, frameworks

I was just reading a post from Justin Etheredge in which he wrote *"... I get so jealous when I talk to the Java guys at work and see all of the freaking awesome tools that they have for free on their platform. Since I use the NUnit, NCover, NHibernate, NAnt stack when doing most .NET development, sometimes I feel like we are just a bunch of copycats"*.

What other cool frameworks exist that aren't on .NET and I may not know about? Can we leave out things which have a direct or pretty reasonable analogue, just the kewl shiznit!

PS we aren't so bad. I'm pretty sure NDepend started out on .NET and has moved to Java

PPS one answer per item please! It makes it a lot easier to discuss them!

Answer (score 2):

http://ruby.sadi.st/Heckle.html

> Think you write good tests? Not bloody
>   likely... Put it to the test with
>   heckle. It’ll put your code into
>   submission in seconds.
>
> The premise is really really simple to
>   understand:
>
> ★ Your tests should pass. ★ Break your
>   code. ★ Now they should fail.
>
> You could check this by hand, but why
>   bother? Use heckle and put it to the
>   test:
>
> heckle -f ClassName
>
> For each failure heckle points out,
>   you've got a test to write.
>
> Chances are, your tests suck.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should ask the Java folks (add some Java tag), .NET tag watchers may not know about Java frameworks .NET does not have :)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/) - A library for tracking, managing and applying database changes.
2. A decent embedded webserver, such as [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/)
3. A build system equivalent to [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
4. An embedded AD/LDAP server for development purposes, such as [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/)

Comment: Well, there is an open source project that connects directly to Maven for builds, and integrates with Visual Studio: http://npanday.codeplex.com/

Comment: Whats so great about Liquibase compared to Tarantino, Migrator.Net etc.?

Comment: @mcintyre - From what I can see with Tarantino it seems to only work with Sql Server. As for migrator.net i'm not sure if db schema configuration should be in code, but it does seem like an interesting project.

Comment: @Jon - I didn't realise there was such a project, I'll go and check it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.terracotta.org/ A kind of distributed JVM which shares objects automatically across a farm. Or something. Reading http://willcode4beer.com/design.jsp?set=kill_your_db makes it sound pretty cool.

Comment: While not exactly the same thing, Microsoft has a distributed cache project called Velocity - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx

Comment: Velocity is similar to memcached really. Terracotta goes WAY beyond that as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

At work, we use the [ATG e-commerce platform](http://www.atg.com/en/ecommerce-suite/), [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/) to run our local builds and [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to build everything.  We also have components from the [Struts](http://struts.apache.org) framework.

Personally speaking, I prefer the [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about) Framework.  [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_Control) is my new favourite pattern!

Comment: I sure wouldn't want to see struts (i'm assuming you're referring to struts 1.x) in .net ;) There's asp.net mvc nowadays.  

There are a ton of IoC frameworks in .net as well, such as spring.net and ninject.

Comment: ATG?  You have my sympathies.  I wouldn't cite that as a Java platform I'd be proud of.  I'm not that keen on Struts either, after seeing Spring and its MVC implementation.

Comment: @duffymo There is no pride in this statement!  TBH, I misread this thread and simply posted what Java tools I'm familiar with and use regularly.