# What OS software is missing in the .NET world?

Tags: .net, open-source

I'm a .NET developer working alongside Java and Eclipse developers. They seem to work with a lot more Open Source than I ever have. Some/Most seem to have made it across to .NET (Hibernate to NHibernate is a great example of this.)

But I am curious as to what OS software out there **hasn't** made it to the .NET world? What do people feel is missing. I'm interested in both business applications and development tools.

*(Background: Asking this question to myself made me think realise that I would like to fill in the holes, if there are any.)*

Thanks

Edit: In light of the recent CodePlex foundation creation perhaps the answers here might suggest the kind of projects we'll see coming along.

Edit: Great responses so far, please keep 'em coming.

Comment: A noble idea, yet to me, port OPs frameworks into another language is about the most boring dev work I could dream of. Thankfully, not everyone is like me!

Comment: Fair enough comment @spender. I love software creation but I also enjoy improving things either thorugh features/design elegance/minimalistic approach/anything else. Otherwise I could not remain engaged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443222/what-cool-frameworks-are-there-on-java-ruby-etc-that-dont-exist-on-net/1443260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadoop is a good example.

http://hadoop.apache.org/

AFIAK there is no open source .NET equivalent. It's a shame really, it's a really nice framework for clustered software.

Another example is the GNU Scientific Library:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

I would say that in general math/science routines are very lacking in .NET, IMO .NET is currently heavily biased towards the data driven developer, as apposed to the scientific developer. For reference: System.Data is a massive namespace, System.Math is a single simple *class*. :)

Answer (score 2):

SharpDevelop still needs a lot of work to be a viable counterpart to Eclipse, so if you're into tools, that'd be a great place to contribute.

Other than the still experimental Machine.Migrations, I don't think there's a good equivalent to Rails-style database migrations.

Comment: What functions/features of Eclipse are not catered for by SharpDevelop? I've never used Eclipse so I'm not sure what sets it apart.

Comment: Well, a mature and broad suite of available plugins, better stability (though I've certainly crashed both), better built-in refactoring tools, better code introspection tools... The interaction model in SharpDevelop is more comfortable if you're used to Visual Studio, and the frequent switching of modes in Eclipse are frustrating, but Eclipse is just a lot further along, which is natural for a large-scale open source project with lots of corporate backing.

Answer (score 1):

Well (for example) as hacked up and unsecure as Wordpress is, it's still a lot more full featured than BlogEngine.net.  And as much as I thought the learning curve on Drupal was too steep, I found the ASP.NET CMS products dominated the territory that lay between expensive and unusable.

Until recently, Microsoft has fought the open source community instead of courting it, and for their part, many of my fellow users of Microsoft tools share my expectation of being paid for our work.

Comment: The whole CodePlex Foundation creation has got me thinking about this and right now it might be a lot of fun to get involved. Thanks.

Comment: "Open source" and "being paid" are not mutually exclusive concepts.

Comment: Yup, you should always remind your bosses that Open Source tools leave more money for the salary of the tool users :)

Comment: To be sure, Rob, there's an exception to everything.  Now if you'll excuse me, I have to bail before we get into how it's OK to write web sites in assembly language. :)